# Should I use system_category or generic_category for errno on Unix?

Tags: unix, error-handling, c++11, errno, system-error

C++0x has two predefined `error_category` objects: `generic_category()` and `system_category()`. From what I have understood so far, `system_category()` should be used for errors returned by the operating system, and `generic_category()` should be used for the generic values found in `std::errc`, which correspond to `errno` values.

However, what should be done on Unix-like systems, where `errno` values *are* the errors returned by the operating system? Should I use `system_category()` (which would be wrong on non-Unix-like systems, needing an `#ifdef`), or should I use `generic_category()` (which would be wrong on Unix-like systems for non-standard `errno` values)?

Comment: After reading the answers I am still unsure what to use.

Comment: @robert: <system_error> is a convoluted, over-designed mess. How to use that properly? Nobody knows ... (see this thread).

Answer (score 2):

You are meant to report errors from OS (any one, including POSIX-based OSes such as Unix) using `system_category()` as C++ standard library functions do - see the quote from C++11 standard below:

> 17.6.5.14 Value of error codes [value.error.codes]
>
> 1 Certain functions in the C++ standard library report errors via a std::error_code (19.5.2.1) object. **That
> object’s category() member shall return std::system_category() for errors originating from the operating
> system**, or a reference to an implementation-defined error_category object for errors originating
> elsewhere. The implementation shall define the possible values of value() for each of these error categories.
> [ Example: For operating systems that are based on POSIX, implementations are encouraged to define the
> std::system_category() values as identical to the POSIX errno values, with additional values as defined
> by the operating system’s documentation. Implementations for operating systems that are not based
> on POSIX are encouraged to define values identical to the operating system’s values. For errors that do
> not originate from the operating system, the implementation may provide enums for the associated values.
> —end example ]

Comment: Well "from the OS" is not so clear as it sounds. `errno` comes from the libc on Unix (which is part of the OS). On Windows, `errno` comes from a C runtime which is not necessarily part of the OS. And you cannot use `system_category` for `errno` anyway on Windows, as this should be reserved for native windows errors. However if you do a `fopen`, in both case you would like to handle `errno` the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `system_category` unless you are in fact the operating system (or reporting an error from an OS-specific function). The category describes where the error originates from, not necessarily what the error code means. So it is perfectly legitimate to have the set of possible error codes from `system_category` be the same as `generic_category`.

Comment: Let's see if I am getting it: I should always use `system_category()`, since the `errno` value I have came from an operating system function (or from a function which called an operating system function, or from a function which called a function which called...). But what to do on Win32, since `system_category()` would be for `GetLastError()` values, and the C library functions would report the errors in `errno`?

Comment: @CesarB - That sounds like the exact opposite of what Nicol Bolas wrote. :) If the errno was already set by a function you called, why mess with it? But if you do need to mess with it, Nicol is advising you to use `generic_category`.

Comment: @Marc: I am calling a function which sets errno (for instance `epoll_ctl` or `open`), and I want to throw a `system_error` (wrapping the errno) in case of error.